# Cuba-platform : Gantt Chart segments overlap

Tags: java, xml, amcharts, cuba-platform

I'm currently developing a web-based project management app, based on Cuba-platform 7.2.
I wanted to add a Gantt view, so I get Charts plugin derived from amCharts.

The issue I'm facing is that for a project (one line of the chart), I can have tasks overlapping from a timeline point of view. As a result, those tasks overlap each other in the Gantt chart, making it not very easy to analyze.
I was wondering if there would be a way to stack segments associated to a line, instead of having them all aligned and overlapping ?

I thank you very much for your help and time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you glebfox for your answer.
As a solution, I finally decided to create one Gantt by project, and for each one, I use a Service to provide a list of transcient entities containing a list Task with only one segment (1 by task), so that each one is on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to provide a solution without inspecting chart configuration and data samples, so I can suggest two options:

1. Replace `startDate` and `endDate` with `duration`. The first segment can have an optional `start` value. In this case, segments will be stacked to each other, e.g.:

[image]

2. Since you don't need to reflect the real segment positions on the timeline, you can replace **Gantt Chart** with **Stacked Bar Chart**, e.g. you can get the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first of all thank you very much for your time !
I will try to be clearer in the description of my entities, and the result I would like to get.
I have several "Project" entities each one having a list of "Task" entities. Each "Task" entity has a startDate and an endDate.
In order to populate my Gantt chart, the dataContainer is a Collection of all "Project" entities, and I use the "Task" entities set of each "Project" as segmentsField.
The problem is that "Task" entities of a "Project" may overlap each other from a timeline point of view (for example Task 1 will run from March to July and Task 2 from May to October).

So for now, the result I get looks like the following :

What I have for now : https://i.stack.imgur.com/px1FZ.png
What I would like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEt7P.png

Of course, if I have multiple projects, the same display would follow for each.
Do you think it is possible ?

As an alternate solution, I was thinking of linking the Gannt chart to a DataContainer of all the "Task" entities, but I didn't find out how to define the root entity as its own "segmentField". Maybe it is too "exotic" usage of this chart...

Comment: Unfortunately, overlapping segments is the way how _amcharts_ handles the situation you have. According to this amcharts [sample](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/overlapping-segments-gantt-chart-rollover-effect/), the workaround could be using semi-transparent segments with different colors.